# How to loop or foreach it

Tags: php, mysqli

I cannot foreach loop my comment & reply system. I read many article and example but can't apply these in my case.

This is my comment system with reply, here every think is working well. But reply form work for only last/new comment. So i need to loop each comment. But can't do, please help me.

```
global $dbh;

$results = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM comments_lite WHERE qazi_id='$tutid' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));

echo'<div class="comments"><div id="updates"><div class="content"><comment>';

// Show only main comment

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) 
{   $id = $row['id'];
    $qazi_id = $row['qazi_id'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $description = $row['description'];     
    $parent_id = $row['parent_id'];
    $date = $row['date'];
//echo comment
    echo'<div class="comment">
            <div class="cdomment_cheder">';
    echo'<p><a href="#"  title="">'.$username.'</a> Says:</p>';
    echo'<span>'.$date.'</span><br/>
        <div class="avatarcnt">
            <img alt="" src="uploadprofile/'.$u_imgurl.'"/>
        </div></div></div>
        <div class="cdomment_text">';
        if ($description=="") {echo '';}
        else echo''.htmlentities($description).'<br>';
        echo '</div>';

//reply
echo'<div class="reply_box"><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="reply" id="'.$id.'">Reply</a></div>';

//Reply form

echo'<div id="loader"></div><div class="reply_here" id="reply_here-'.$id.'" style="display:none;">
        <form action="" method="post" id="repfrm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset id="cmntfs">
                <input type="hidden" name="username" tabindex="1" id="author" value="'.$username.'"/>
                <textarea name="replycom" rows="2" tabindex="4" id="replycom" value=""></textarea>
                <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" id="parent_id" value="0" />
                <input type="hidden" name="tutid2" id="tutid" value="'.$tutid2.'" />
                <button type="submit" name="submit" value="" tabindex="5" id="submit" class="repfrm">Post Reply</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>';

// Show Reply of each comment
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments_reply WHERE parent_id ='".$id."'";
$res = mysqli_query($dbh,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) 
{   $id = $row['id'];
    $qazi_id = $row['qazi_id'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $description = $row['description'];     
    $parent_id = $row['parent_id'];
    $date = $row['date'];
//echo reply
        echo' <div class="rcontent"><replycomment><ul>
            <div class="comment">
            <div class="cdomment_cheder">';
echo'<p class="name"><a href="#" title="">'.$username.'</a> Says:</p>';
            echo'<span>'.$date.'</span><br/>
                <div class="avatarcnt">
                    <img alt="" src="uploadprofile/'.$u_imgurl.'"/>
                </div></div></div>
                <div class="cdomment_text">';
                    if ($description=="") {echo '';}
                    else echo''.htmlentities($description).'<br>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo'</ul><replycomment></div>';

        }   //reply while close 
    }   //comment while close
    echo'</div><comment></div>';
```

Comment: You can't loop on two queries at the same time from the same connection. You need to bring into PHP space ALL the results of the first query, and then loop on them and then do the second query, OR use unbuffered queries.

Comment: Ok, sir i am trying. Thank you.

Comment: I am newbie sir, can u help me to do it please. Or few guideline to do it. thank you.

Comment: fetch all the results of the first query into an array, and then loop on the array with foreach. The rest is the same.